# Azure blob encryption Key vs KeyResolver

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-keyvault

I have implemented blob encryption with Azure KeyVault (based on[this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-encrypt-decrypt-blobs-key-vault)). 
There is one thing however, that I don't fully understand and that's the exact purpose of a KeyResolver. Specifically this: `// In this case, we will not pass a key and only pass the resolver because
// this policy will only be used for downloading / decrypting.
BlobEncryptionPolicy policy = new BlobEncryptionPolicy(null, cloudResolver);`

I don't think I need a KeyResolver, because on application startup I get the key from KeyVault and register it on my UnityContainer, so it's available on the repository that handles upload and downloads of blobs. Am I correct? Or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't think I need a KeyResolver, because on application startup I get the key from KeyVault and register it on my UnityContainer, so it's available on the repository that handles upload and downloads of blobs. Am I correct? Or is there something I'm missing?

Base on my understanding, if we don't want to store the Key info into KeyVault then we no need to use KeyResolver, we could use the key as we like for encryption and decryption blob .

```
RsaKey key = new RsaKey("your private Key");
BlobEncryptionPolicy policy = new BlobEncryptionPolicy(key, null);
BlobRequestOptions options = new BlobRequestOptions() { 
EncryptionPolicy = policy };
```

We can get more info about  Key vs KeyResolver from [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-client-side-encryption). The following is snippet from the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-client-side-encryption).

> While creating an EncryptionPolicy object, users can provide only a Key (implementing IKey), only a resolver (implementing IKeyResolver), or both.
>
> IKey is the basic key type that is identified using a key identifier and that provides the logic for wrapping/unwrapping. 
>   IKeyResolver is used to resolve a key during the decryption process. It defines a ResolveKey method that returns an IKey given a key identifier. This provides users the ability to choose between multiple keys that are managed in multiple locations.
>
> - For encryption, the key is used always and the absence of a key will result in an error.
> - For decryption:
>     The key resolver is invoked if specified to get the key. If the resolver is specified but does not have a mapping for the key identifier, an error is thrown.
>     If resolver is not specified but a key is specified, the key is used if its identifier matches the required key identifier. If the identifier does not match, an error is thrown.

Comment: "When we encryption or decrption the blob, then we need to use the same EncryptionPolicy object. That meanings if we encryption blob with KeyResolver, then we need KeyResolver to decryption the blob." - That's not true, even the tutorial uses only a key while uploading (encrypting) and a resolver while downloading (decrypting) a blob. Which is precisely the situation in my question